# Share via Facebook and Twitter Titanium SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, titanium, share

I use [this module](https://github.com/viezel/TiSocial.Framework) on my project.

I have three Ti.Ui.Switch on a screen. If I checked them all and press button, I should share (same text and image) via Facebook and Twitter. The most important thing, user should have possibility to post this text and image without confirmation popup.

If I try Social.twitter(for example), after click on button, user must confirm post again... How can i circumvent this feature?

How i can do this?

```
sharePhotoButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        fbShare();
        twShare();
        emailShare();
     });    

function fbShare(){
        if(fbSwitch.value){
            if(Social.isFacebookSupported()){
                Social.facebook({
                    text: commentArea.value,
                    image: event.media
                });
            }
        }
    };
    function twShare(){
        if(twSwitch.value){
            if(Social.isTwitterSupported()){
                Social.twitter({
                    text: commentArea.value,
                    image: event.media
                });
            }
        }
    };

    function emailShare(){
        if(emailSwitch.value){
            var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
            if(emailDialog.isSupported()){
                emailDialog.messageBody = commentArea.value;
                emailDialog.open();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: It helps people answer if you include code or instructions for what you have tried so that they can correct or augment your effort.

Comment: Ok, add code to question.

Comment: If I try Social.twitter(for example), after click on button, user must confirm post again... How can i circumvent this feature?